# Alternative to std::istream in c++

Tags: c++, eos, eosio

I have the next code but I'm using it in an eosio smart contract so get this error:

> use of overloaded operator '>>' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::istream'

I think that the problem is because I don't use the header `#include <iostream>` because I can't include this because is in conflict with the header `<eosio>`.

This is a part of my code:

```
std::vector<Record>  data;

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Record& data)
{
   return str >> data.from >> data.to >> data.rate;
}
```

I'm looking for an alternative to std::istream to can rewrite my code in another way to can include it in the eosio smart contract.

Is there a way or another code that can use and replace this?

Comment: If you have code that requires the use of `std::istream` then the header must be included. Full stop. The only alternative is to use operating system-specific low level file reading functions. And it's a very low quality library if it's headers conflict with `<iostream>`. That's bonkers.

Comment: Do you have `using namespace` statements in your code or (hopefully not) in any of the headers you include from the library?

Comment: what is `<eosio>` ? why is it in conclift with `iostream` ? Isnt that the actual problem you should get fixed?

Comment: The problem is more likely that you have several conflicting declarations of the overload.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: Judging by the error message, `<iostream>` is actually already included indirectly.